# Randomly Select Set with Defined Variable(s)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to accomplishing the following:

1. Define multiple sets of variables
2. Use PHP to randomly select a set
3. Echo data from selected set throughout page

Below is a sample of the logic with dummy variables and data:

**--- DEFINE EACH SET ---**

```
SET 1 {
title1 = Sample School
text1 = School is great
link1 = school-page.php
}

SET 2 {
title2 = Sample Business
text2 = Business is great
link2 = biz-page.php
}

SET 3 {
title3 = Sample Organization
text2 = Organization is great
link3 = org-page.php
}
```

**--- OUTPUT VARIABLES FOR SELECTED SET WITHIN PAGE ---**

```
<h1><?php echo $title(from selected set) ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $text(from selected set) ?></p>
<div>Visit page <a href="<?php echo $link(from selected set) ?>">here</a></div>
```